# Remove duplicate records in Excel sheet using python

Tags: excel, pandas, python-3.10

I used below code to remove duplicates based on "Name" and "Discription" column from an Excel sheet, but it didn't worked.
Can anyone explain the reason or can anyone suggest another method to remmove duplicate?
`df = pd.read_excel("file_path") df.drop_duplicates(subset=["Name","Discription"], keep='first') df.to_excel("New.xlsx",index=False)`
It gives same file with duplicates as New.xlsx file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reassign your dataframe before saving the new spreadsheet:

```
df= df.drop_duplicates(subset=["Name","Discription"], keep="first")
```

Or use `inplace=True` :

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=["Name","Discription"], keep="first", inplace=True)
```

In one bloc:

```
(
    pd.read_excel("file_path")
        .drop_duplicates(subset=["Name","Discription"], keep="first")
        .to_excel("New.xlsx", index=False)
)
```

Comment: df.drop_duplicates(subset=["Name","Discription"], keep="first", inplace=True) This worked. Thanks a lot.